# How to pull data from a website into Excel?

Tags: microsoft-excel

For example,

If I wanted the cheapest price of this item displayed in cell A2 of my Excel spreadsheet, is there any code I could write to do it? This is not continuously scraping data. Maybe finding the price once a day/week.

http://steamcommunity.com/market/listings/440/Strange%20Hillbilly%20Speed-Bump

Comment: Welcome!  We're not a code writing service.  What have you tried already?  Where exactly are you getting stuck implementing this?

Comment: Hi. I'm not looking for code. I'm looking for pointers. Not sure where to start exactly because I've never done this before

Comment: Code is how you tell a computer to find, collect, and handle data. Anything more than copy/paste will require code unless the data source has already provided a way to access the data in your preferred format.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Here is a basic example to get you going. It shows how to display a website as just the HTML code. From there you will have to determine how to read what is on the page you have converted to text but at least it is a start:

```
Private Sub GetWebsiteHtml_Click()

Dim x As Long, y As Long
Dim htmlText As Object

Set htmlText = CreateObject("htmlFile")

With CreateObject("msxml2.xmlhttp")
    .Open "GET", "http://google.com", False
    .send
    htmlText.body.innerHTML = .responsetext
End With

End Sub
```

htmlText will be the variable containing your website. I used google for my example.

Comment: No problem. Glad to help :)

Comment: Hi Eric F, I can't figure out how to display the htmlText in the excel sheet itself. Range ("A1").Value = htmlText results in just [object] on the sheet. Can you please tell me how i can get the htmlText on the page?